# Can't get artisan queue:work to process jobs with Supervisor on Elastic Beanstalk (Laravel/Redis)

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-artisan

We are trying to process a Redis queue with the Laravel Artisan Daemon Queue Listener.

Running the command php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work --tries=3 directly when logged in to one of the EC2-servers over SSH works perfectly every time. However, when running this command via Supervisor nothing happens.

In our .ebextensions-folder we have a scripts file containing the following configuration necessary to copy our supervisor configuration to a folder on to the machine:

```
    01-migration:
        command: "php /var/app/ondeck/artisan migrate --force && php /var/app/ondeck/artisan db:seed --force"
        leader_only: true

    02-supervisor:
        command: "mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ && cat eb/laravel-worker.conf > /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf && cat eb/supervisord.conf > /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf && mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor/ && touch /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log"
```

**laravel-worker.conf**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:listen --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=webapp
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/app/current/storage/worker.log
```

We can see the processes being created:

Screenshot of the processes running

We also can't see anything happening in the logfiles (worker.log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding lifeofguenter's configuration on GitHub, we noticed that supervisor couldn't read our environment variables.

This line enlightened us:

```
# make sure elasticbeanstalk PARAMS are being passed through to supervisord
. /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
```

*Source: https://gist.github.com/lifeofguenter/f8ea93f10a403807a719*